# Symfony (4) - How do I couple environment type with a default database?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I've noticed that `packages->doctrine.yaml->doctrine->dbal->connections->[connectiontype]`
is where you can configure the database name, but connectiontype is not the same thing as environmenttype.

So currently I have to type it in twofold `php bin/console server:run --env=dev --connection=dev` and that's one time too many in my book.

What if I forget and accidentally am in the production database while thinking I am in the development database?

Thus I want a default database for every environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm beginning to think that the answer is to create a `packages->dev->doctrine.yaml->doctrine->dbal->connections->[connectiontype]`

Comment: Sorry, I am probably not fully understanding your question, but...in Symfony 4, I believe the idea is to leave the environment details (prod, dev and testing) defined in the `YOURPROJECT/.env` file - why doesn't this work?

Comment: I wouldn't know how. I've only seen the dotenv file as a place to set environment variables.